# Calculating Document Frequency in HashMap java

Tags: java, database, tf-idf

I'm trying to achieve counting TF-IDF in java with DB as the corpus of document. I have done calculating the Term Frequency store in hashmap, but i have a problem, how can i calculate the document frequency each term? eg. the term "president" occurs in which document id? and how many it occurs in other document? i have 3 documents in DB for training, im stuck here, any advice? and thanks for helping, here is my code:

```
 try{

     Map <String,Integer> kamus = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

     k.Koneksi();
     String sql = "select * from data_berita";
     Statement n = k.koneksi.createStatement();
     ResultSet res = n.executeQuery(sql);

       while(res.next()){
           int id = res.getInt("id");
           String konten = res.getString("konten");
           String f = konten.replaceAll("[-?/<>_+=!@#%&*.“”‘’()$·,';:{}|\"]", "").toLowerCase();
           String [] array = f.split("\\s+");

           for(String s : array){
               int fl = 1;
               k.Koneksi();
               String sq = "Select * from StopWord";
               Statement stat = k.koneksi.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sq);

               while(rs.next()){
                    if(s.equals(rs.getString("Stopword"))){
                        fl=0;
                  }
               }

               if (fl!=0){       
                   if(kamus.containsKey(s)){
                      kamus.put(s, kamus.get(s)+1);
                   }
                   else{
                      kamus.put(s, 1);
                   }
               }

           }
           for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> en : kamus.entrySet()){
               String d = en.getKey();
               Integer s = en.getValue();
               System.out.println(d+" "+s);

           }
```

and this is the result of term frequency(not all):

alliance=1, president=3, suzhou=3, unloading=1, attended=1, liquefied=1, bright=1

Comment: Have you tried a `HashMap<String,Set>` with Term as Key and DocumentIDs as Values in the Set? The Set takes care of eliminating duplicates. Then your IDF is the size of the set, am I correct?

Comment: any e.g code? that i'll get what i'm to do

Comment: You do pretty much the same as with `kamus` only you create a HashMap<String,Set>. Instead of incrementing the value, you add DocID to the Value(i.e. the Set). Since Sets cannot contain duplicates, you will end up with term->set of docids where it occured. And the size of the set is giving you the number of documents the term occurs in. That's what you wanted if I understand correctly.

Comment: let me try it, thanks

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837788/how-can-i-calculate-total-number-of-term-frequency-in-all-collection-s-document